# Adding legend to multiline ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to add a legend to my plot at ggplot. The dataset can be seen in

```
   percent       KNN  logistic       LDA       QDA
1     0.10 0.7393658 0.2815159 0.2907966 0.2737819
2     0.20 0.4926279 0.2558543 0.2723330 0.2619254
3     0.30 0.4631474 0.2539841 0.2579681 0.2569721
4     0.40 0.3995381 0.2448037 0.2471132 0.2471132
5     0.50 0.3400538 0.2258065 0.2271505 0.2298387
6     0.60 0.3287671 0.2226027 0.2208904 0.2243151
7     0.75 0.3834808 0.2684366 0.2684366 0.2743363
8     0.80 0.3771626 0.2664360 0.2698962 0.2733564
9     0.90 0.3509934 0.2582781 0.2649007 0.2516556
10    0.99 0.2727273 0.3636364 0.3636364 0.3181818
```

The thing is that it doesn't let use the names of the columns as guide to create the legend of the plot. The code I used to create the plot is the following:

```
Default <- (ggplot(default_error, aes(x = percentages, colour = variable))
            + geom_line(aes(y = KNN), color = "darkred")
            + geom_line(aes(y = logistic), color = "steelblue")
            + geom_line(aes(y = LDA), color = "green")
            + geom_line(aes(y = QDA), color = "coral3")
       + labs(y = "Error rate", x = "Percentage", title = "Default Error", color = "Method")
       + theme_linedraw()
       + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 25),
               legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
               legend.position = "right",
               axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
               axis.text = element_text(size = 15, angle = 0, vjust = 0.8, hjust = 0.7),
               plot.title = element_text (face = NULL, hjust = 0, size = 30, family = "montse", vjust = 0),
               plot.subtitle = element_text (face = NULL, hjust = 0.5, size = 10, family = "montse", vjust = 0))
       + scale_color_discrete(name = "Method", labels = c("KNN", "Logistic","LDA","QDA")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
default_error <- pivot_longer(default_error, names(default_error)[-1])
```

Then you don't need all the geom_lines, and the colors can be given in `scale_color_manual()`:

```
(ggplot(x, aes(x = percent, y = value, colour = name))
  + geom_line()
  + labs(y = "Error rate", x = "Percentage", title = "Default Error", color = "Method")
  + theme_linedraw()
  + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 25),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.position = "right",
          axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 15, angle = 0, vjust = 0.8, hjust = 0.7),
          plot.title = element_text (face = NULL, hjust = 0, size = 30, family = "montse", vjust = 0),
          plot.subtitle = element_text (face = NULL, hjust = 0.5, size = 10, vjust = 0))
  + scale_color_manual(name = "Method", 
                         values = c(KNN = "darkred", logistic = "steelblue", LDA = "green", QDA = "coral3"),
                         labels = c("KNN", "Logistic","LDA","QDA")))
```

That should do it.

In the future, please make sure to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).